# Location request plugin not prompting user to turn location on

Tags: cordova-plugins

I'm using the [cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy) plugin to prompt the user to turn location on (if not already on). However the prompt doesn't show, and I get the following error

> Accuracy request failed: error code=4; error message=User chose not to make required location settings changes.

Here is the part of the code I've called the plugin

```
function init() { 
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", watchPosition, false);
}

function watchPosition() {

    cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable(); // enable backgroundMode 

    // Check if location settings are turned on. Prompt user if not turned on
    function onRequestSuccess(success){
        console.log("Successfully requested accuracy: "+success.message);
    }

    function onRequestFailure(error){
        console.error("Accuracy request failed: error code="+error.code+"; error message="+error.message);
        if(error.code !== cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.ERROR_USER_DISAGREED){
            if(window.confirm("Failed to automatically set Location Mode to 'High Accuracy'. Would you like to switch to the Location Settings page and do this manually?")){
                cordova.plugins.diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings();
            }
        }
    }

    cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.request(onRequestSuccess, onRequestFailure, cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.REQUEST_PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    // start geolocation

    checkPeriodically = setInterval(checkTime, 10000);

    var watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options); 

    ...
```

The rest of the program runs fine (when the location is manually switched on). What is causing this to fail? Thanks.

Comment: Which OS (with version) does it give you that error?

Comment: Samsung Android 4.4.4. 

I managed to get the plugin working with a skeleton app test. That is, just a call to that plugin with the default setup and no other code. For some reason it's not working with the code I'm currently using.

Comment: The runtime permissions are available starting from Android 6.0 https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html